# How to fix: 80040154 Class not registered in Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net

I have a seriously big bug, and I can't fix it. When I build my project, there is an exception thrown saying

> 80040154 Class not registered.

I've tried to change the platform to x86, but it didn't work. And many other things...

Here the problem occurs:

```
Dim Cam As New HyCam2.HyCam2
```

Whole code here:

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim Cam As New HyCam2.HyCam2

    Private Sub CheckBox3_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles CheckBox3.CheckedChanged
        If CheckBox3.Checked = True Then
            Cam.AddClickStarbursts = True
        End If
        If CheckBox3.Checked = False Then
            Cam.AddClickStarbursts = False
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button7_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button7.Click
        Cam.PauseRec()
    End Sub

    Private Sub TextBox2_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox2.TextChanged
        TextBox2.Text = Cam.Height
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        Cam.SelectRegion()
        TextBox1.Text = Cam.Width
        TextBox2.Text = Cam.Height
        TextBox3.Text = Cam.StartX
        TextBox4.Text = Cam.StartY
    End Sub

    Private Sub CheckBox1_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles CheckBox1.CheckedChanged
        If CheckBox1.Checked = True Then
            Cam.RecordCursor = True
        End If
        If CheckBox1.Checked = False Then
            Cam.RecordCursor = False
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub CheckBox2_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles CheckBox2.CheckedChanged
        If CheckBox2.Checked = True Then
            Cam.RecordSound = True
        End If
        If CheckBox2.Checked = False Then
            Cam.RecordSound = False
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Me.Hide()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
        Cam.SelectWindow()
        TextBox1.Text = Cam.Width
        TextBox2.Text = Cam.Height
        TextBox3.Text = Cam.StartX
        TextBox4.Text = Cam.StartY
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button4_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click
        Cam.Play()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button5_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button5.Click
        Cam.StartRec()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button6_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button6.Click
        Cam.StopRec()
    End Sub

    Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged

    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        TextBox1.Text = Cam.Width
    End Sub

    Private Sub TextBox3_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox3.TextChanged
        TextBox3.Text = Cam.StartX
    End Sub

    Private Sub TextBox4_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox4.TextChanged
        TextBox4.Text = Cam.StartY
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: https://hyperionics.com/forum2/tm.aspx?m=10625

Comment: How that link will help me? I didn't understand anything.